# XSLT Xpath wildcard

Tags: xml, xslt, select, xpath, wildcard

I've just started learning XML & XSLT and have a quick question regarding Xpath.

**Here's the XML code:**

```
<root>

<shop>
    <person> 
        <employee> 
            <name> Alexis </name> 
            <role> Manager </role> 
            <task> Sales </task> 
        </employee> 
    </person>
</shop>

<person> 
    <employee> 
        <role> Supervisor </role> 
        <name> Blake </name> 
        <task> Control </task> 
    </employee> 
</person>


</root>
```

**and here's the XSLT code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="root"> 
<html><head></head> 
<body><xsl:apply-templates/> 
</body> 
</html> 
</xsl:template> 


<xsl:template match="shop"> 
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/*/*"/> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="employee"> 
<u> <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/> </u> 
(Task: <xsl:apply-templates select="task"/>) 
<br></br> 
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="person2"> 
<xsl:apply-templates /> 
</xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output is:**

```
Alexis (Task: Sales )
Blake (Task: Control )
Blake (Task: Control )
```

What I don't understand is why the last part is duplicated? I know that it's due to this part of the XSLT code:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/*/*"/>
```

but that's only because I was fiddling around with the code and displaying it in Firefox. I don't understand why though.

From what I understand, it's selecting all the grandchildren elements of "root", like so:

root/shop/person

but why isn't Alexis repeated as well? Only Blake is repeated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **root** matching template, you do `<xsl:apply-templates/>` which will pick the first **shop** and **person** elements. With respect to the **person** element, there isn't a specific template for this, and so XSLT will continue to match its child elements and pick up the **employee** for 'Blake'

However, there is a matching template for **shop** and the issue is indeed with what you do in the template that matches it.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/*/*"/>
```

Because you have started the xpath expression with `/root` this will start mathing relative to the root element of the document, and not the **shop** element you are currently positioned on. This means it will select the elements **/root/shop/person** and **/root/person/employee** which leads to your duplicate 'Blake'.  However, as you are not matching the employee element for 'Alexis' elsewhere, this is only output once.

You probably need to do just this instead, to match the **employee** element

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
```

This will match all grand-children of the current element. `*` will match the child element, and so `*/*` will match the child elements of the child elements.

However, if the intent is to output just the **employee** elements, you can simplify your XSLT by taking advantage of the fact that the default template matching behaviour for an element is to process its child elements. Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

   <xsl:template match="root">
      <html>
         <head/>
         <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="employee">
      <u>
         <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
      </u>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' (Task:', task, ')')"/>
      <br/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <u> Alexis </u> (Task: Sales )<br>
      <u> Blake </u> (Task: Control )<br>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply! 

I'm not trying to make it show only just the employees or anything, it's just an exam question that I want to understand.

I understand how you get:

/root/shop/person and /root/person/employee

but since employee is a child of person for this part:
/root/shop/person/employee

then why isn't Alexis also part of the duplicated output?


Also, what exactly does this do * / *??

Comment: I've expanded my answer to hopefully try and explain a bit more, and what `*/*` means.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Could you also answer this too:

I understand how you get: /root/shop/person and /root/person/employee but since employee is a child of person for this part: /root/shop/person/employee then why isn't Alexis also part of the duplicated output?

Comment: This is because you only look for /root/shop/person/employee within the template for the **shop** element. It is not matched elsewhere in the XSLT. However, the /root/person/ element is selected firstly by the `<xsl:apply-templates/>` within the **root** template, and then again by the `<xsl:apply-templates select="/root/*/*"/>` within the **shop** template.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now!

Sorry just one more question (the more I do these examples, the more questions I have :P )

I sort of understand how the wildcard works, but still slightly confused. Looking at this code: "/root/*/*" I understand that we start from the root folder, and go down 2 child levels. So we get /root/shop/person and /root/person/employee.

I tend to think of this as opening a folder on Windows. The /root/person/employee will open the employee folder and then output Blake as the result. I'm fine with that, however the /root/shop/person folder still contains an employee folder.

Comment: So what I don't understand is, if /root/shop/person still contains an employee folder that is yet to be opened, how can it output Alexis? If it's like /root/shop/person/employee, then I can understand because the current level you're accessing is employee. But in our case it's not, so I don't understand how Alexis is part of the result.....

Comment: This is due to the default behaviour of XSLT. You select the folder /root/shop/person, but you have not got an explicit template in your XSLT to match a **person** element. In this case, the default behaviour of XSLT to to continue matching all the child elements of the element, and so it will end up matching the **employee** element.

Comment: Ahh I see, ya I thought it might have to do with some default rules with XML. I was wondering why it didn't go even deeper into the further child levels. I was experimenting with the code in Firefox and found out that it can access the direct child level relative to the current one, but no further than that.

Anyway, I've learned a lot today! Thank you so much for your help, and I appreciate your quick replies!

Comment: @shadowz1337: [Re: the more I do these examples, the more questions I have] -- then ask *new* questions! And dont forget to accept the best answer for a given question. Hint: accepting an answer is done by clicking the check-mark next to it.